# View.view.layout(l, t, r, b)

Tags: android

How does View.view.layout work in Android? 
I can't seem to figure out a consistent behavior. 
If it's positioning, why are 4 coordinates required and not just 2? 
Does this mean that it scales as well as positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the second phase of the layout mechanism. (The first is measuring). In this phase, each parent calls layout on all of its children to position them. This is typically done using the child measurements that were stored in the measure pass(). Derived classes with children should override onLayout. In that method, they should call layout on each of their their children.

[Check out the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/view/View.java#View.layout%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29)